# start outlook and open calendar using applescript

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I know how to start outlook:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
   activate
   set folderName to "Calendar"
end tell
```

but the `set folderName` does not seem to open the calendar view

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385984/scripting-office-outlook-2016-on-mac  "you can open Outlook's script dictionary by choosing "Open Dictionary" from the File menu and selecting the Microsoft Outlook application" Which should give you the information you need.

Comment: There is no "Open dictionary " in the File menu in 16.37

Comment: Oh, duh, from the script editor. Thanks!

Comment: OK so I found that but I still don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will open Microsoft Outlook, bring it to the front, and set the view to Calendar view.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    activate
    set theWindow to first main window
    set the view of theWindow to calendar view
end tell
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: You are my hero